# Заменить все вхождения "ключевых слов" на одноименные поля объекта

Tags: javascript

Нужно заменить в строке все вхождения "ключевых слов" на соответствующие им поля объекта. "Ключевое слово" всегда начинается с `#` (если необходимо, может и заканчиваться этим символом), само слово полностью соответствует имени поля.

```
var html = '<span class = "#class">#text</span>';
var obj = {
    class: 'class1',
    text: 'Span Text'
};
```

Подскажите, как это можно было бы реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения, можно воспользоваться заменой по регулярному выражению. Для этого у строк есть метод [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Регулярное выражение может быть следующим: `#(\w+)` - выбирается подстрока начинающаяся с `#` и в которую входят символы из набора: `A-Za-z0-9_`.

Вторым параметром, [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) может принимать функцию подстановки, параметрами, которой являются найденные подстроки и указанные группы.

Функция может выглядеть так:

```
function(_, $1) { // первый параметр не важен, во втором приходит содержимое группы, а именно "class" или "text" из примера, без #
  return obj[$1] || $1; // если есть поле в объекте возвращаем значение, иначе оставляем как есть
}
```

Пример в сборе:

```js
var html = '<span class = "#class">#text</span>';
var obj = {
  class: 'class1',
  text: 'Span Text'
};

console.log(html.replace(/#(\w+)/g, function(_, $1) {
  return obj[$1] || $1;
}))
```